# Spring MVC + Hibernate : BeanCreationException error after regenerating model classes

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a Spring MVC + Hibernate application that has been working perfectly for a while : my model classes have been generated by Hibernate from my MySQL databese.

I made DAO objects and services for interactions between the application and the database. Everything was working fine.

Today I updated the "Site" table of my database. When I re-generated the classes of the model with Hibernate, problems arrived.

Since, I get the *org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'appConfig'* when I try to start my Tomcat Server.

What did I miss ? Here are my AppConfig class and the Site.java class that has been generated. If I replace it by the previous one, everything works fine again.

**EDIT**

```
mai 15, 2017 3:50:44 PM org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext refresh
AVERTISSEMENT: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'appConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.sggsmi.bending.converter.RoleToUserProfileConverter com.sggsmi.bending.configuration.AppConfig.roleToUserProfileConverter; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'roleToUserProfileConverter': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.sggsmi.bending.service.UserProfileService com.sggsmi.bending.converter.RoleToUserProfileConverter.userProfileService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userProfileService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.sggsmi.bending.dao.UserProfileDao com.sggsmi.bending.service.UserProfileServiceImpl.dao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userProfileDao': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.sggsmi.bending.dao.AbstractDao.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/sggsmi/bending/configuration/HibernateConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.sggsmi.bending.model.Machine.setups in com.sggsmi.bending.model.Setup.machines
mai 15, 2017 3:50:44 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
GRAVE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'appConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.sggsmi.bending.converter.RoleToUserProfileConverter com.sggsmi.bending.configuration.AppConfig.roleToUserProfileConverter; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'roleToUserProfileConverter': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.sggsmi.bending.service.UserProfileService com.sggsmi.bending.converter.RoleToUserProfileConverter.userProfileService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userProfileService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.sggsmi.bending.dao.UserProfileDao com.sggsmi.bending.service.UserProfileServiceImpl.dao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userProfileDao': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.sggsmi.bending.dao.AbstractDao.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/sggsmi/bending/configuration/HibernateConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.sggsmi.bending.model.Machine.setups in com.sggsmi.bending.model.Setup.machines
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:368)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.initMessageSource(AbstractApplicationContext.java:697)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:526)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4730)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5194)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1406)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.sggsmi.bending.converter.RoleToUserProfileConverter com.sggsmi.bending.configuration.AppConfig.roleToUserProfileConverter; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'roleToUserProfileConverter': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.sggsmi.bending.service.UserProfileService com.sggsmi.bending.converter.RoleToUserProfileConverter.userProfileService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userProfileService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.sggsmi.bending.dao.UserProfileDao com.sggsmi.bending.service.UserProfileServiceImpl.dao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userProfileDao': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.sggsmi.bending.dao.AbstractDao.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/sggsmi/bending/configuration/HibernateConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.sggsmi.bending.model.Machine.setups in com.sggsmi.bending.model.Setup.machines
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'roleToUserProfileConverter': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.sggsmi.bending.service.UserProfileService com.sggsmi.bending.converter.RoleToUserProfileConverter.userProfileService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userProfileService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.sggsmi.bending.dao.UserProfileDao com.sggsmi.bending.service.UserProfileServiceImpl.dao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userProfileDao': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.sggsmi.bending.dao.AbstractDao.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/sggsmi/bending/configuration/HibernateConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.sggsmi.bending.model.Machine.setups in com.sggsmi.bending.model.Setup.machines
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1192)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.sggsmi.bending.service.UserProfileService com.sggsmi.bending.converter.RoleToUserProfileConverter.userProfileService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userProfileService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.sggsmi.bending.dao.UserProfileDao com.sggsmi.bending.service.UserProfileServiceImpl.dao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userProfileDao': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.sggsmi.bending.dao.AbstractDao.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/sggsmi/bending/configuration/HibernateConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.sggsmi.bending.model.Machine.setups in com.sggsmi.bending.model.Setup.machines
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userProfileService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.sggsmi.bending.dao.UserProfileDao com.sggsmi.bending.service.UserProfileServiceImpl.dao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userProfileDao': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.sggsmi.bending.dao.AbstractDao.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/sggsmi/bending/configuration/HibernateConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.sggsmi.bending.model.Machine.setups in com.sggsmi.bending.model.Setup.machines
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1192)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545)
    ... 45 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.sggsmi.bending.dao.UserProfileDao com.sggsmi.bending.service.UserProfileServiceImpl.dao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userProfileDao': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.sggsmi.bending.dao.AbstractDao.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/sggsmi/bending/configuration/HibernateConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.sggsmi.bending.model.Machine.setups in com.sggsmi.bending.model.Setup.machines
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 56 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userProfileDao': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.sggsmi.bending.dao.AbstractDao.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/sggsmi/bending/configuration/HibernateConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.sggsmi.bending.model.Machine.setups in com.sggsmi.bending.model.Setup.machines
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1192)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545)
    ... 58 more
```

**EDIT 2**

Machine.java

```
package com.sggsmi.bending.model;
// Generated 15 mai 2017 16:18:03 by Hibernate Tools 5.1.0.Beta1

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

/**
 * Machine generated by hbm2java
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "machine", catalog = "bec")
public class Machine implements java.io.Serializable {

    private int machineId;
    private Site site;
    private String machineName;

    public Machine() {
    }

    public Machine(int machineId, Site site, String machineName) {
        this.machineId = machineId;
        this.site = site;
        this.machineName = machineName;
    }

    @Id

    @Column(name = "machineId", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public int getMachineId() {
        return this.machineId;
    }

    public void setMachineId(int machineId) {
        this.machineId = machineId;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "siteId", nullable = false)
    public Site getSite() {
        return this.site;
    }

    public void setSite(Site site) {
        this.site = site;
    }

    @Column(name = "machineName", nullable = false, length = 50)
    public String getMachineName() {
        return this.machineName;
    }

    public void setMachineName(String machineName) {
        this.machineName = machineName;
    }

}
```

Setup.java

```
package com.sggsmi.bending.model;
// Generated 24 mars 2017 17:13:20 by Hibernate Tools 5.1.0.Beta1

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

/**
 * Setup generated by hbm2java
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "setup", catalog = "bec")
public class Setup implements java.io.Serializable {

    private int setupId;
    private boolean pbi;
    private boolean shape;
    private float widthMin;
    private float widthMax;
    private float heightMin;
    private float heightMax;
    private int retrait;
    private Set<Machine> machines = new HashSet<Machine>(0);
    private Set<Articles> articleses = new HashSet<Articles>(0);

    public Setup() {
    }

    public Setup(int setupId, boolean pbi, boolean shape, float widthMin, float widthMax, float heightMin,
            float heightMax, int retrait) {
        this.setupId = setupId;
        this.pbi = pbi;
        this.shape = shape;
        this.widthMin = widthMin;
        this.widthMax = widthMax;
        this.heightMin = heightMin;
        this.heightMax = heightMax;
        this.retrait = retrait;
    }

    public Setup(int setupId, boolean pbi, boolean shape, float widthMin, float widthMax, float heightMin,
            float heightMax, int retrait, Set<Machine> machines, Set<Articles> articleses) {
        this.setupId = setupId;
        this.pbi = pbi;
        this.shape = shape;
        this.widthMin = widthMin;
        this.widthMax = widthMax;
        this.heightMin = heightMin;
        this.heightMax = heightMax;
        this.retrait = retrait;
        this.machines = machines;
        this.articleses = articleses;
    }

    @Id

    @Column(name = "setupId", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public int getSetupId() {
        return this.setupId;
    }

    public void setSetupId(int setupId) {
        this.setupId = setupId;
    }

    @Column(name = "pbi", nullable = false)
    public boolean isPbi() {
        return this.pbi;
    }

    public void setPbi(boolean pbi) {
        this.pbi = pbi;
    }

    @Column(name = "shape", nullable = false)
    public boolean isShape() {
        return this.shape;
    }

    public void setShape(boolean shape) {
        this.shape = shape;
    }

    @Column(name = "widthMin", nullable = false, precision = 12, scale = 0)
    public float getWidthMin() {
        return this.widthMin;
    }

    public void setWidthMin(float widthMin) {
        this.widthMin = widthMin;
    }

    @Column(name = "widthMax", nullable = false, precision = 12, scale = 0)
    public float getWidthMax() {
        return this.widthMax;
    }

    public void setWidthMax(float widthMax) {
        this.widthMax = widthMax;
    }

    @Column(name = "heightMin", nullable = false, precision = 12, scale = 0)
    public float getHeightMin() {
        return this.heightMin;
    }

    public void setHeightMin(float heightMin) {
        this.heightMin = heightMin;
    }

    @Column(name = "heightMax", nullable = false, precision = 12, scale = 0)
    public float getHeightMax() {
        return this.heightMax;
    }

    public void setHeightMax(float heightMax) {
        this.heightMax = heightMax;
    }

    @Column(name = "retrait", nullable = false)
    public int getRetrait() {
        return this.retrait;
    }

    public void setRetrait(int retrait) {
        this.retrait = retrait;
    }

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "setups")
    public Set<Machine> getMachines() {
        return this.machines;
    }

    public void setMachines(Set<Machine> machines) {
        this.machines = machines;
    }

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "setuparticle", catalog = "bec", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "setupId", nullable = false, updatable = false) }, inverseJoinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "artId", nullable = false, updatable = false) })
    public Set<Articles> getArticleses() {
        return this.articleses;
    }

    public void setArticleses(Set<Articles> articleses) {
        this.articleses = articleses;
    }

}
```

Comment: And full stacktrace please

Comment: I added most of it but I am limited to 30000 characters.

Comment: From the trace mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.sggsmi.bending.model.Machine.setups in com.sggsmi.bending.model.Setup.machines. It's something wrong with your Entities referenced to unknown, not mapped property

Comment: Didn't notice this, thanks.

Comment: I added Machine and Setup, if you see what is causing the problem.
Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the trace mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.sggsmi.bending.model.Machine.setups in com.sggsmi.bending.model.Setup.machines. It's something wrong with your Entities referenced to unknown, not mapped property

You have in the Setup entity

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "setups")
public Set<Machine> getMachines() {
    return this.machines;
}
```

But there is no setups in the Machine.

They linked as ManyToMany so you need to point relations table `Machine_Setup` (don't know how it's actually called in your DB)

Answer (score 1):

It appears the relationship between `Setup` and `Machine` is what is causing your issue.

This error typically happens when one entity is included in the mapping configuration and the other entity is not or when the `mappedBy` attribute of the annotation points to an incorrectly named property in the referenced target entity class.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'm looking for the error, I added the two classes in my post, tell me if you see where the problem is.
Thanks for your answer !

Comment: Your `Setup#getMachines` has `mappedBy="setups"` which implies you should have a property/mapping in `Machine` called `setups` which doesn't appear to exist as my answer suggests.